# A generic type as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics

My first question is, is it possible to specify a generic type as a parameter,
secondly, is anything such as the pseudo code ive listed below possible?

I assume it will be using .net 4.0 and the dynamics modifier but i am more interested in a pre 4.0 solution.

```
    public static void SomeMethod(List<T> l, Type type, Control samplecontrol)
    {
     l.Add((type)samplecontrol);
    }
```

Edit:

Here is my solution...

```
    public static void FindControlRecursive<T>(Control parent, List<T> l)
    {
        foreach (var ctrl in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(T))
                l.Add((T)ctrl);
            if (((Control)ctrl).Controls != null && ((Control)ctrl).Controls.Count > 0)
                foreach (Control _ctrl in ((Control)ctrl).Controls)
                    FindControlRecursive<T>(_ctrl, l);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looking at this comparison: `ctrl.GetType() == typeof(T)` - are you sure it's what you actually want? If you pass e.g. `ButtonBase` as `T`, it won't match `Button` or `CheckBox` (which both derive from `ButtonBase`). Perhaps you want `ctrl is T` instead? Also, you don't need the cast in `Add((T)ctrl)` and all the `(Control)ctrl` if you write `foreach (Control ctrl ...)` rather than `foreach (var ctrol ...)` - the problem with the latter is that `Controls` collection isn't generic, so `var` is inferred to `object.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean this?

```
public static void SomeMethod<T>(List<T> l, T item)
{
    l.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the generic type modified to the method name. That will replace your type parameter that you were trying to pass in,

```
public static Add<T>(List<T> l, T samplecontrol)
{
 l.Add(samplecontrol);
}
```

You can also add type qualifiers onto the method

```
public static Add<T>(List<T> l, T samplecontrol) 
    where T : Control
{
 l.Add(samplecontrol);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public static void YourMethodName<T>(List<T> l, Control samplecontrol)
{
    l.Add((T)samplecontrol);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, and has been since C# 2.0. This is probably the syntax you are looking for:

```
public static void AddControlToList<T>(List<T> list, Control sampleControl)
{
    list.Add((T)sampleControl)
}
```